# Print the first five lines of the text being held in the scalar value

Tags: regex, perl, printing, lines

I have manipulated the text that is being held in the scalar value but now however I only want to keep five lines and the code and print it. I am unsure of how to go about doing this.

```
use WWW::Wikipedia;

my $wiki = WWW::Wikipedia->new();

## search for 'perl' 

my $result = $wiki->search( 'perl' );

## if the entry has some text print it out

## This is where I want the five lines to
##  be printed

if ( $result->text() ) { 
    my $rawtext = $result->text();
    print $result->text();
}

## list any related items we can look up
print join( "\n", $result->related() );
```

Comment: What five lines do you mean: e.g. do you mean _the first_ 5 lines or _the last_ 5 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, not necessarily the best way, to do it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "Line of data\n" x 8;  # Generate sample data in single scalar variable

print "Before: <<$var>>\n";

my @lines;

@lines[0..4] = split /\n/, $var;  # Capture just the first 5 lines

print "After:  <<$_>>\n" for @lines;
```

Example output:

```
Before: <<Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
Line of data
>>
After:  <<Line of data>>
After:  <<Line of data>>
After:  <<Line of data>>
After:  <<Line of data>>
After:  <<Line of data>>
```

---

#### After the update to the question

After installing [WWW::Wikipedia](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3AWikipedia), this trivial adaptation of your code works for me (Perl 5.18.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS derivative).  I regard it as a proof by counter-example that your ["it won't work for me"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132901/i-wanted-to-know-how-to-print-the-first-five-lines-of-the-text-being-held-in-the/24133422?noredirect=1#comment37266664_24133422) claim is incorrect — or, at least, whatever you tried (which you've not shown) was not the correct thing to try.  Note that this code includes the improvements [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132901/i-wanted-to-know-how-to-print-the-first-five-lines-of-the-text-being-held-in-the/24133422?noredirect=1#comment37241684_24133422) by [Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069567/pierre).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Wikipedia;

my $wiki = WWW::Wikipedia->new();

## search for 'perl' 

my $result = $wiki->search( 'perl' );

## if the entry has some text print it out

## This is where I want the five lines to
##  be printed

if ( $result->text() ) { 
    my $rawtext = $result->text();
    print "Raw: [[$rawtext]]\n";
    $rawtext =~ s/\n\n+/\n/g;  # Remove repeated newlines
    $rawtext =~ s/^\n//;       # Remove leading newlines
    my @lines;
    @lines[0..4] = split "\n", $rawtext, 6;
    print "Line: <<$_>>\n" for @lines;
}
```

Output:

```
Raw: [[

{{Infobox programming language
| name = Perl logo = paradigm = multi-paradigm: functional, imperative, object-
| oriented (class-based), reflective, procedural, Event-driven, generic year =
| 1987 designer = Larry Wall developer = Larry Wall latest_release_version =
| 5.20.0<ref></ref> latest_release_date = latest preview version =
| 5.21.0<ref></ref> latest preview date = turing-complete = Yes typing = Dynamic
| influenced_by = AWK, Smalltalk 80, Lisp, C, C++, sed, Unix shell, Pascal
| influenced = Python, PHP, Ruby, ECMAScript, LPC, Windows PowerShell,
| JavaScript, Falcon, Perl 6, Qore programming_language = C operating_system =
| Cross-platform license = GNU General Public License or Artistic License<ref
| name='licensing'></ref> website = file_ext = .pl .pm .t .pod wikibooks = Perl
| Programming
}}

'Perl' is a family of high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic
programming languages. The languages in this family include Perl 5 and Perl
6.<ref></ref>

Though Perl is not officially an acronym,<ref></ref> there are various
backronyms in use, such as: Practical [[data extraction|Extraction]] and
Reporting Language.<ref></ref> Perl was originally developed by Larry Wall in
1987 as a general-purpose Unix scripting language to make report processing
easier.<ref name='sheppard00'></ref> Since then, it has undergone many changes
and revisions. The latest major stable revision of Perl 5 is 5.20, released in
May 2014. Perl 6, which began as a redesign of Perl 5 in 2000, eventually
evolved into a separate language. Both languages continue to be developed
independently by different development teams and liberally borrow ideas from
one another.

The Perl languages borrow features from other programming languages including C,
shell scripting (sh), AWK, and sed.<ref name="perltimeline"></ref> They provide
powerful text processing facilities without the arbitrary data-length limits of
many contemporary Unix commandline tools,<ref name="programmingperl"></ref>
facilitating easy manipulation of text files. Perl 5 gained widespread
popularity in the late 1990s as a CGI scripting language, in part due to its
parsing abilities.<ref name='roderick02'></ref>

In addition to CGI, Perl 5 is used for graphics programming, system
administration, network programming, finance, bioinformatics, and other
applications. It is nicknamed "the Swiss Army chainsaw <!-- Note to editors.
This should read *chainsaw*, not knife. Check the ref -->of scripting languages"
because of its flexibility and power,<ref></ref> and possibly also because of
its "ugliness".<ref></ref> In 1998, it was also referred to as the "duct tape
that holds the Internet together", in reference to both its ubiquitous use as a
glue language and its inelegance.<ref name='leonard98'></ref>
]]
Line: <<{{Infobox programming language>>
Line: <<| name = Perl logo = paradigm = multi-paradigm: functional, imperative, object->>
Line: <<| oriented (class-based), reflective, procedural, Event-driven, generic year =>>
Line: <<| 1987 designer = Larry Wall developer = Larry Wall latest_release_version =>>
Line: <<| 5.20.0<ref></ref> latest_release_date = latest preview version =>>
```

Comment: you can avoid unnecessary split using a third argument. also there is no need for a regex here. @lines[0..4] = split "\n", $var, 6;

Comment: Actually this did not work at all for me. I am using a wikipedia module called text_basic and using a scalar variable to store the data. It is about 30-40 lines but I only want to keep the first five lines of the text.

Comment: OK; now you've updated your question...Your code says you're using [WWW::Wikipedia](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3AWikipedia), not something called 'text_basic'.  The `$rawtext` variable is set but not used. Your `$rawtext` should match my `$var`.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is working perfectly now. One question have you ever created Perl Modules? And if so is it possible to create a perl module package while using another inside of this package?

Comment: Yes ([DBD::Informix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3AInformix)).  Yes: there are both internal packages (DBD::Informix::*) and external packages (DBI) used in DBD::Informix.  Plenty of modules have multiple dependencies on external modules.  Just make sure you list them all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want five lines of data explicitly, then you can use the following regular expression `/((?:.*\n){5})/`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = '';
$var .= "Line $_ of data\n" for (1..10);

print "Before: <<$var>>\n";

if ($var =~ /((?:.*\n){5})/) {
    print "Five lines: <<$1>>\n";
} else {
    warn "No match, less than 5 lines";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Before: <<Line 1 of data
Line 2 of data
Line 3 of data
Line 4 of data
Line 5 of data
Line 6 of data
Line 7 of data
Line 8 of data
Line 9 of data
Line 10 of data
>>
Five lines: <<Line 1 of data
Line 2 of data
Line 3 of data
Line 4 of data
Line 5 of data
>>
```

If you want to always match if there is less than 5 lines available, you just need to adjust the regex slightly to:

```
if ($var =~ /((?:.*\n?){1,5})/) {
```